# How to add a timer to my slideshow in HTLM5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

---

I have a working manual slideshow on my page but I want to add an automatic function to it as well while displaying the correct image order on the slideshow controls, I tried tinkering with the Java script but the best i could do is to add a timer which accelerates in speed after using one of the slideshow's controls.

Here's my code:

Source Code:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container container" style="max-width:800px; padding-top:5%">

  <img class="mySlides" src="images/cheese.png" style="height:300px; width:800px">

  <img class="mySlides" src="images/beverages.png" style="height:300px; width:800px">

  <img class="mySlides" src="images/caramel2.png" style="height:300px; width:800px">

  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">

    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>

    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>

    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>

    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>

    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.w3-tooltip,.w3-display-container{position:relative}.w3-tooltip .w3-text{display:none}.w3-tooltip:hover .w3-text{display:inline-block}
.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-hover{display:block}.w3-display-container:hover span.w3-display-hover{display:inline-block}.w3-display-hover{display:none}
.w3-left-align{text-align:left!important}.w3-right-align{text-align:right!important}.w3-justify{text-align:justify!important}.w3-center{text-align:center!important}
.w3-container:after,.w3-container:before,.w3-panel:after,.w3-panel:before,.w3-row:after,.w3-row:before,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-container,.w3-panel{padding:0.01em 16px}.w3-panel{margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:16px}
.w3-section,.w3-code{margin-top:16px!important;margin-bottom:16px!important}
.w3-tiny{font-size:10px!important}.w3-small{font-size:12px!important}.w3-medium{font-size:15px!important}.w3-large{font-size:18px!important}
.w3-text-white,.w3-hover-text-white:hover{color:#fff!important}
.w3-display-bottommiddle{position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0;transform:translate(-50%,0%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%)}
.w3-left{float:left!important}.w3-right{float:right!important}
.w3-text-khaki,.w3-hover-text-khaki:hover{color:#b4aa50!important}
.w3-badge,.w3-tag{background-color:#000;color:#fff;display:inline-block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;text-align:center}.w3-badge{border-radius:50%}
.w3-border-0{border:0!important}.w3-border{border:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-top{border-top:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-bottom{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-left{border-left:1px solid #ccc!important}.w3-border-right{border-right:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-transparent,.w3-hover-none:hover{background-color:transparent!important}
.w3-white,.w3-hover-white:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#fff!important}
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
```

Java Script:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

P.S: The code is not mine I've used the code from https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots2

Answer (score 0):

i think the idea behind this is after you create the timer you should store its time in a variable like if it is 10 s it will save in the variable and then you will do in js event like when its hit the tenth second show the next picture i think it will be easy if you use vue.js Framework bcs it has the show command and you can set it to true or false so you will do an alert box on the tenth second and if the user clicked yes then show will be true and the next photo will appear unfortunately i can't give you a stable code for now